# Do I have to use the same prepareCall when using addBatch & executeBatch? Why?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc

I'm new to using JDBC and am learning how to use batch processing. After wasting a lot of time trying to figure out why my combination of JavaScript and SQL stored procs didn't work, I think I learned that you have to use one `prepareCall` when using `addBatch` and `executeBatch`. Is this true? If so, why?

To exemplify, here's some example input:

```
var vals = [["value1_1","value2_1","value3","value4","value5","value6_1"],
    ["value1_2","value2_2","value3","value4","value5","value6_2"]]
```

The below loop works as expected. Note that I `prepareCall` before entering the loop.

```
params = Array(vals.length).fill("?") 
pstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call "+storedProcedure+"("+params+")}");

for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) { // for each array

    for (var j = 0; j < vals[i].length; j++) { // for each value within each array
        // set the string
        pstmt.setString(j+1, vals[i][j]); 
    }
    
    pstmt.addBatch();
  } 

try {

    pstmt.executeBatch();
    
  } catch (err) {
    //my err msg code
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Now, sometimes I have records that have a different number of parameters so I thought that I could just move `prepareCall` into the first loop so that I can change the number of parameters as needed for each input array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) { // for each array
    // moved prepareCall here
    params = Array(vals.length).fill("?") 
    pstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call "+storedProcedure+"("+params+")}");

    for (var j = 0; j < vals[i].length; j++) { // for each value within each array
        // set the string
        pstmt.setString(j+1, vals[i][j]); 
    }
    
    pstmt.addBatch();
  } 

try {

    pstmt.executeBatch();
    
  } catch (err) {
    //my err msg code
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

For this second loop, I don't get any errors from Javascript but I get a foreign constraint error from my stored proc. My stored proc makes a set of `CALL`s to create records based on the value of the last parameter. I understand that the error that I get is telling me that one of the `FK`s doesn't exist. This would only happen if the wrong set of `CALL`s was invoked or the right set of `CALL`s was invoked but one of the `CALL`s failed. I'm sure neither is the issue since the first loop works as expected.

Thus, I'm interested to learn why I have to use one `prepareCall` when I `executeBatch`? To confirm, I have to use totally separate `prepareCall`s when I have call different stored procedures with different numbers of parameters?

I don't think it matters but for good measure: I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `prepareCall` returns a `CallableStatement` object that is compiled for the specific statement that you passed to `prepareCall`. When you call `addBatch`, the set of parameters is added to that specific instance of `CallableStatement`. If you execute `prepareCall` again, you get a **different** `CallableStatement` handle, with its own batch.

So, in your second piece of code in each iteration of the outer loop, you create a **new** `CallableStatement`, losing the previous callable statement and its batch (creating a memory leak as well in your code and possibly in your DBMS). As a result, when you call `executeBatch`, you will only execute the **last** statement you prepared, with only a single set of parameter values.

If you need to execute distinct statement texts, you will need to prepare and execute them in order, and you cannot use batch(*).

---

<sup>* - You could use batch if multiple sets of parameters use the same statement text, but if there are order dependencies between different statement texts, this might get tricky</sup>